# Unable to read from external storage using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm using NDK to load user sound files from the Music folder.
I get my file path from ACTION_PICK intent and it looks like this:

> /storage/emulated/0/Music/My Narration - 0007.wav

I don't have any problems in debug mode but it fails in release: **File could not be opened.**

I'm also loading image files from the external storage with Java using JNI and there are no problems.

I have this permission in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have also tried adding this, but it has no effect:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

To open a file I'm using **open()** from **fcntl.h**:

```
open(filePath, O_RDONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR  | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
```

Why does it work in debug mode but not in release?

Comment: No idea but did you try to use fopen instead ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks like I found the source of a problem.
Debug and Release versions of the app use different code controlled by a #define flag, and Release version has a bug.